# Hide a picklist value

Tags: configuration

I ve to assign two different record types for two different user. One user has to view an additional picklist value in "Status" picklist in Case object whereas another user should not be able to view that. How can this get done ?

Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create 2 support processes for this.  Lets say SP1, SP2.  And associate the correct case status values to both.

Now create 2 Record Types (RT1 and RT2).  While creating record types, you need to associate them with a Support Process.  So, RT1 will be associated with SP1 and RT2 with SP2. This way, when you assign the "record types" to your profiles, the corresponding support processes (and in turn the case status values) are assigned to the profiles.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly
User1 - recordtype1 - in status picklist with additional value 
User2 - recordtype2 - in status picklist with no additional value - this can be controlled in the recordtype page.. select the recordtype and edit the status picklist for the same recordtype and remove the value from selected column..

Comment: yeah you are right !! but we cannot simply edit the Status picklist values in the case object. In order to do that, we have to create a support process for that. But still i cant accomplish the requirement